# set form as invalid in mvc using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form in MVC4 i want to mark it as in valid in case of some custom errors added using jquery.

jquery Code: To add invalid class to the view

```
$('#Phone_Number').attr('class', 'input-validation-error');
```

This class gets added but i can still submit the form with the class.

```
The Html that gets generated for the above field is
<input class="input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-length="should not be over 50 characters" data-val-length-max="50" data-val-regex="Incorrect Format" data-val-regex-pattern="^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$" data-val-required="is required" id="Phone_Number" name="Phone_Number" type="text" value="">
```

When i click on submit the class is changed back to valid.

Controller has :

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //todo: Log 
                return new Message { MessageTitle = "Invalid request" };
            }
```

I get `ModelState.IsValid= true` always

Comment: you need to handle the click event of your submit button (or a submit event), check if the form is valid and if it is not then prevent the default behavior of the submit button. You should still do full validation on the server side too

Comment: Would be easier to help seeing relevant HTML code...

Comment: musefan it is handled in the controller i get the form as valid